# category links don't work

Tags: joomla-3.x, category, t3-framework, id, purity-iii

On my site there are 2 types of categories:

the first has link `mysite.com/id-category` and in this case I cannot see the content of the page (the div with id "t3-mainbody"  is missing in the generated HTML code).

The second type of category has link `mysite-com/category` and this works.

At the same time, the articles of the first category (link like `mysite.com/id-category/id-article`) don't work (the div with id "t3-mainbody"  is missing in the generated HTML code), but the articles of the second category work (link like`mysite-com/category/article`).

I use Joomla 3.9.19 and the Purity III theme (t3 framework).

How can I fix the first type of links?

Comment: Do you have the menu item created for the category? Please provide us more info so that we can help you with your problem.

Comment: Ok, I have understood the problem: if a category hasn't his menù item, all the articles of that category are broken. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Global Configuration > Search Engine Friendly URLs: OFF

Do the "broken" pages now work?

Content > Articles > Options > "Integration" tab

"URL Routing" - is this set to Legacy or Modern? If "Modern" is set, what is "Remove IDs from URLs" set to?

Comment: An "answer" with this many question marks in it is usually Not An Answer.  If you would like to ask the OP for additional question details, please do so as a comment instead of an answer.  Please only answer after the question has provided sufficient clarity to confidently give an answer.